# States between Transparent, Translucent and Opaque

Tags: single-word-requests, colors

I started creating a color palette for a side project and I was thinking what words would fit the best to describe alpha (transparency) of color.

Imagine we have 0 for totally clear (every light passes through) and 7 for absolutely opaque (nothing passes through). 4 can be translucent, 6 could be hazy or foggy.

**How would you name states between Transparent > Translucent > Opaque?**

*Not a native English speaker.*

Comment: What about "semi-translucent" and "semi-opaque" ?

Comment: If a modestly technical classification is needed it's generally the case to assign some numerical value to the "degree" of transparency.

Comment: Technically, *translucent* is **not** halfway between *transparent* and *opaque*. Both *translucent* and *transparent* pass light; *opaque* does not. A 50% translucent object would pass the same amount of light as a 50% transparent one. Only in ordinary speech is *translucent* considered a synonym of *semi-transparent*.

Answer (score 1):

Translucency and opacity are usually considered antonyms of practically opposing values. Here is a description as applied to HTML. http://www.dev-hq.net/html-css/20--opacity-transparency

Both are usually given in percent thus fully transparent is 100% translucent or 0% opacity 
Conversely fully opaque is 100% opacity and 0% translucency.

The scale is sometimes reduced to points such that equal opacity and translucency would be a value of 0.5 each.

I have not seen a scale of 7 points, however I think there was one ranking a number of words, for example inks are graded as :-

> Transparent
>   Semi-transparent
>   Semi-opaque
>   and Opaque

for a better description of the relativity of these terms see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparency_and_translucency

Comment: You are mixing *transparency* and *translucency*; the two are not interchangeable: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparency_and_translucency

Comment: Given the context of the question, I think it would be best to stick to the "scientific" terms (which are known to most people who deal with color in media (e.g. art directors and graphic designers). See also my comment to question: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/479945/states-between-transparent-translucent-and-opaque/479951?noredirect=1#comment1158490_479945

Answer (score 1):

The degree of light is not what differentiates the connotation of those words.The flavor of transparent is that an image behind a transparent item can be identified. Translucent implies that light is transmitted but that information is not clearly transmitted. A dark, clear, glass is transparent, a cloudy diffusing glass that might transmit more total light is translucent.